# Adjust the textArea height and width to fit in <td> of a table

Tags: html

I am displaying the html content in a table. For printing the tags i am using `textArea` in the `<td>` of the table. So i want to adjust the height and width of `textArea` so that it is equal to the `<td>`. How can i do this

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[dabblet.demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2893830)
[image]

#### the problem is that textarea behave not normal box-model, that's why we need this trick with box-sizing

this `CSS` will help you:

```
textarea {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* FF1+ */
            box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
}
```

### if you have no access to `css` file, you can use inline css

like this:

```
<textarea style="border: none; width: 100%; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using this CSS:

```
td textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

Or inline:

```
<td>
    <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none">
    </textarea>
</td>
```

Comment: Don't for get to add `box-sizing: border-box`, otherwise the padding and border of the textarea will cause it to be bigger than the table cell.

Comment: can i do this in the `<textArea>` itself without using css

Comment: @user1275375 yes, put it in the "style" attribute in the textarea tag.

Comment: @user1275375 I have created a fiddle on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Qqa4/. `border: 0;` is necessary for the `textarea` to make it fit just right.

Comment: Thank you for the example but i want this to include in style attribute of `textArea` how can i do it

Comment: @VladimirStarkov - Did you actually look at my updated example? Here is some inline CSS: `<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0">`

Comment: @VladimirStarkov - Okay. Also, `border: none;` like in your answer is better.

Comment: Um, are y'all under the impression that this works for the height? Because as even a rudimentary test will reveal, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

When I added "min-width:98%;" it worked.  I'm using jquery datatables.

Answer (score -2):

give the textarea a 100% width and height style

```
td textarea {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

but also take into account the paddings and borders or the textarea so that it would not overflow from the td.

hope this helps.