# Textarea inside table cell doesn't resize to cell height under Firefox

Tags: html, textarea, html-table

When I place a textarea inside a table cell...

```
<table style="height:200px">
    <tr>
        <td>Some<br>nifty<br>text<br>filler</td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <div style="height:100% !important">
                <textarea style="resize:none; height:100% !important; width:100% !important" data-ng-model="modelLogin.inpMtext">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...and I take extra care to make sure that both the textarea and the containing div have an important height of 100%... the textarea indeed covers all the cell's height under Chrome, but not under Firefox.

Any idea why and/or how to fix the situation under Firefox?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943721/3063226, using box-sizing: border-box; for the textarea is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla does it perfectly right! You assign a textarea's height of 100% of it's parent. And it's parent (div) is 100% of its parent (td) height. Td height is undefined, so it can't stretch to feet the whole height. [one might think that td's height = table's height, but this assumption is not quite right] 
To fix it, you have to assign 100% height to  like so:

```
<td style="height:100%">
```

The rule is simple: if you apply the width/height/margins in percents, make sure that your browser has a benchmark to calculate it (every parent until the final height has to have it's height).

If it doesn't help, add display:block to textarea (not quite sure it's really needed)
And... You can delete these nasty inline styles with multiple !importants :-)

Comment: Also the <tr> element should have 100% height.