# jQuery.expandingTextarea not working inside a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, textarea, html-table

When running the jQuery plugin [bgrins/ExpandingTextareas](http://bgrins.github.io/ExpandingTextareas/) ([*github*](https://github.com/bgrins/ExpandingTextareas)), `<textarea>` tags inside 100%-width tables do not work as expected. In particular, the textarea does not expand vertically as desired, and the horizontal position of the textarea has an incorrect offset that changes as one inputs text.

Here is a [sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/4QcaR/) illustrating the problem.

I have also opened a corresponding issue, [#33 on GitHub](https://github.com/bgrins/ExpandingTextareas/issues/33).

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to remedy it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please refer to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943721/1642219) for the issue related to textarea inside table cell.

below is what i hope is the solution of your problem

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4QcaR/5/)

**html**

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td id="expand"><textarea placeholder="type here"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

**css**

```
table {
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
}

textarea {
border: none;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

**script**

```
$("textarea").expandingTextarea({
  resize: function() //callback
  {
     var i=$('textarea').height();

   //inspect the textarea and cell containing it, height difference is 4.

     $('#expand').attr('height',i+4+'px');   
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks UDB - That's quite helpful and interesting. The `.css('max-width', '0px')` seems to be essential, but I do not understand what it does, and it does not seem to be mentioned on the linked answer. What does a `max-width` of `0px` do? Cheers

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Even it's hard for me to figure out why `'max-width', '0px'` worked :). i tried `var tdw=$('td').css('width'); tdw=$('td').css('min-width',tdw); ` first but it did not worked so after getting frustrated i used max-width with `100px` but by mistake i forgot to type 100 and typed only 0 :) and it worked finally. One more weired fact about code is that max-width thing will work only when  `0px <= max-width <= 12px`. May be its the plugin or if there is any other reason i think asking a `CSS PRO` will be good to solve the mystery

Comment: Ha! Good to know -- great experimenting. I'm hesitant to rely on undocumented behaviour since it might have unexpected outcomes on different browsers. I wish I knew what was going on here, or how we could replicate the desired outcome with functions working as documented/designed. This might call for another SO question :)

Comment: Here is [some discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907020) – basically the `max-width: 0px` is the same as setting the table sizes to equal, static widths. Fascinating!

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt thanks for the link, now that quirky behavior is clarified

Comment: I will mark this correct when the `max-width` quirk has been removed and replaced with `table-layout: fixed`. I'm just not comfortable marking quirks resulting from undefined behaviour as correct. :) Thanks UDB!

Comment: @BrianmM.Hunt. Thanks for reminding me to correct the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that answer ! In my case `table-layout:fixed` was enaugh to solve problem that was troubling me for whole week !