# What does max-width: 0px do?

Tags: css

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19894562/19212) posted to [jQuery.expandingTextarea not working inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893416) involves the use on a table-cell of `$('td').css('max-width','0px')`.

The solution provided by this answer does not work (at least in Chrome) without this line.

I could not find any documentation on what [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) of `0px` might do, particularly to a table cell. Is there a defined behaviour for it? Or is this just an arbitrary side-effect that happens to result in the desired behaviour?

Although there is an answer to the linked question, I am hesitant to mark it correct based on undefined or undocumented behaviour that may change in the future, so I would like to know more about why `max-width: 0px` works.

Cheers

Comment: and what this `max-width` does with `expanding textarea`?

Comment: max-width: 0px basically prevents the element from expanding itself. In the context of the linked post. It prevents the table cell from expanding based on what's being written in the textarea.

Comment: @AdamBotley: Thanks. Seems that `max-width: 0px` has to be applied to all `<td>` elements. So this would seem to be the same as `width: "100%/n"` where n is the number of `<td>` elements (e.g. with 3 columns `width: 33%`). Is the `max-width` a defined behaviour?

Comment: "I could not find any documentation on what `max-width` of `0px` might do, particularly to a table cell. Is there a defined behaviour for it?" CSS2.1 says that there isn't: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths So I would say that this is a side-effect that just happens to produce the desired behaviour, and even then it's not one that you can always rely on given that it's UB.

Comment: Try using `table-layout: fixed` instead. This fixes the cell widths to the value they are given. So if you do `width: "100%/n"`, they won't resize based on their content and will maintain their set widths. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/893yu/

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock - I've been rummaging through that stuff too. It looks like the formula might be [`min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) and/or the [automatic table layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout).

Comment: @AdamBotley - Thank you. I think `table-layout: fixed` is the best solution to the problem noted in the linked question.

Comment: Good news :) Will post as an answer for people viewing this

Comment: @Adam Botley same as `width`, and it isn't depend on whther textarea ampty or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This fixes the cell widths to the value they are given. So if you do `width: 30%` on the cells, they won't resize based on their content and will maintain their set widths.

If only some of the cells are given a `width` value, the remaining cells will share the space available. Use this functionality as a replacement to `max-width`.

Using `max-width: 0px` is more of a quirk than reliable behaviour.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/893yu)

Comment: Strictly speaking this does not answer the question, but it does provide the desired behaviour that the `max-width: 0px` seems to accomplish.

Comment: I've added a bit more information as to `max-width` on tables and what to use instead. Hopefully this covers the question a bit more