# Why does this behave the way it does with max-width: 0?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-tables

See http://jsfiddle.net/mpx7os95/14/

The behavior is the desired behavior, which allows the center column in a 3 column layout to take up all the space available AND still allow the text inside of it to overflow into ellipsis when shrunk far enough.  This seems to work due to `max-width: 0`, but **why** does it produce this effect?

What's so special about `max-width: 0` in this case?

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.col {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  display: table-cell;
}
.x {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">abc</div>
  <div class="col x">test blah blah blah blah blah zzzzz.</div>
  <div class="col">def</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Note**: It's not just `max-width:0`, it's any width less than the text content's width.

The mixture of `display: table-cell`, `max-width`, and `width:100%` make an interesting situation that the specifications don't explicitly cover. However, by making some observations and thinking, we can understand why we have the same behavior across all major browsers.

`max-width:0` tries to make the element width 0, of course, meaning that everything should be overflow. However, the combination of `display: table-cell` and `width:100%`, as seen in [the linked demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mpx7os95/14/), override that command for the `div` (maybe for the same reason why [`max-width` does not apply to table rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#property)) for the most part. As such, the element displays itself like it would without the `max-width:0` until the width of the `div` is no longer large enough to contain all of the text content.

A thing to note before we continue is that the text itself by default has a width that is set by the characters inside of it. It's kind of a child element of the parent `div`, though there are no tags.

This innate width of the text content is the reason why `max-width:0` is needed to create the effect. Once the width of the `div` is no longer large enough to contain all of the content, the `max-width:0` property enables the width to become less than the width of the text content, but forces the text that can no longer fit to become overflow of the `div` itself. Thus, since the `div` now has text overflow and `text-overflow: ellipsis` is set, the text overflow is ellipsed (if that's a word).

This is very useful to us because otherwise we couldn't make this effect without a lot of messy JavaScript. [Use case demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2q6d2d8/)

<sub>Note: This answer describes the behavior and gives some insight as to *why* this is the case. It doesn't cover *how* `display:table-cell` overrides part of the `max-width`'s effect.</sub>

Comment: This is what I observed, but seemed magical enough to me that I felt like I needed a better understanding...particularly how table-cell affects the relationship between max-width and width, because [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) says that max-width takes precedence over width.  I would love to see some docs or specs that explains this.

Comment: @Lonimor That could potentially be because [`max-width` doesn't apply to table rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#property) - maybe it's the same for table cells?

Comment: I agree with @Lonimor, I would like to see docs or specs that explain the behavior

Comment: @ScottLerch Me too! But since there are none that we can find, what is wrong with speculation? Isn't that the whole point of a Q&A?

Comment: Nothing at all, I don't mind speculation but it's not really an answer.  I'm just trying to encourage an answer backed with citations, I'll upvote your answer after that happens :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier the reality could be close but different on a few or many key aspects, which is where documentation or citations come in handy. Scott isn't saying the answer isn't useful, but rather that he won't endorse it without that bit of extra bit of surety; as you admit, you're mostly guessing here.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I was too

Comment: As far as I understand the child content has a "min-width" value (calculated by the user agent as mentioned above) and somehow adding `max-width: 0` overrides this. So really `max-width: 0` is doing what you would expect `min-width: 0` to do.

Comment: "In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined." [§10.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) cc @Scott Lerch

Answer (score 3):

This is not to be a complete answer, but a contribution.

> What's so special about max-width: 0 in this case?

I'm not sure, but the cell seems to give another chance to adjust. (maybe [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#min-max-widths), algorithm point 2)

According to my experiments applies only replaced elements with intrinsic width. In this case the text block has intrinsic width by white-space: nowrap.

Items without intrinsic width fit well without using max-width: 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/p3dgs19m/

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.col {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    display: table-cell;
}
.a {
    min-width: 80px;
}
.x {
    background: #0cf;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width:100%;
}
.y {
    max-width: 0;
}
.z {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">abc</div>
        <div class="col x">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x50&text=InlineReplacedIntrinsicWidth" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">end</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">abc</div>
        <div class="col x y">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x50&text=InlineReplacedIntrinsicWidthPlusMaxWidth" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">end</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">abc</div>
        <div class="col x z">Intrinsic Width due white-space property set to nowap.</div>
        <div class="col">end</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">abc</div>
        <div class="col x y z">Intrinsic Width due white-space property set to nowap and Max-Width</div>
        <div class="col">end</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">abc</div>
        <div class="col x"><span>IntrinsicWidthduenospacesintextandblahIntrinsicWidthduenospacesintextandblah</div>
        <div class="col">end</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">abc</div>
        <div class="col x y"><span>IntrinsicWidthduenospacesintextandMaxWidth</div>
        <div class="col">end</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">abc</div>
        <div class="col x y">Non Intrinsic Width. Inline, non-replaced elements. <strong> Inline, non-replaced elements. </strong> Inline, non-replaced elements.</div>
        <div class="col">end</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what fact you mention?     ,

Comment: The entire purpose of your answer - `"I want to clarify that works with max-width < width_needed_to_adjust. Not have to be zero."`

Comment: lol.. that's a joke, so I should not make jokes in English. sorry if confused you. The purpose of my answer was to expose my experiments maybe help someone else find a correct answer to this (not well documented) interesting situation. as you said.

Answer (score 3):

I think BoltClock's comment on Zach Saucier's answer - that the behaviour is undefined - is a good reason to avoid relying on the fact that today's browsers happen to exhibit the desired behaviour.

Many people (like me) will arrive at this question not because they have an academic interest in what `max-width: 0` means in *this* case, but because they want to know whether it's OK to use that hack to get the ellipsis to show for text in a table cell, and FWIW I think the answer is: "not really".

A better way to get the ellipsis to work in *that* case is to use "`table-layout: fixed`" on the `<table>` element, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909160/98422).