# Overflow hidden not working with inline-block parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

I know this question was asked but I couldn't find a good solution.
The class `user-info` has two direct children with `inline-block` display and child `user-info-text` has two direct children with `display: block`. When I set both overflow and `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the children it is not working. I know overflow doesn't work for inline elements. 
How can I make it work or why is it not working?

```css
.profile__dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.avatar {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.avatar--circle {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.avatar--md {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}
.user-info>* {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.user-info-text {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.user-info-text>* {
    display: block;
}
.profile__info a, 
.profile__info span, 
.profile__info li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.profile__dropdown li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #777;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    float: initial;
}
.profile__info a {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: initial;
}
.profile__detail a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 30px;
}
.profile__wrapper li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.profile__dropdown li.separate {
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
}
.profile__dropdown li a, .user-info {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="profile__dropdown">
    <li class="user-info">
        <div class="avatar avatar--circle avatar--md"></div>
        <div class="user-info-text"><span>John Joe adfasdfadfadsf</span><span>0011026184</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="separate"><a href="#">Settings adfadfasdfasdfdsfadsf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Running the code snippet shows that the ellipsis is working. Maybe you have an overwrite of your CSS somewhere or there isn't enough here for us to help.

Comment: @Biotox thanks. Yeah working for the setting and logout texts. But not working for the name &a phone no texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN about `text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow):

> This property only affects content that is overflowing a block container element in its *inline* progression direction.

It means you should apply `text-overflow` property to the element with `display: block` to clip its inline content, and also limit the `width` of the element with `display: block`.

In your code snippet, you could add `max-width` to `.user-info` and `overflow: hidden` + `text-overflow: ellipsis` + `white-space: nowrap` to `.user-info-text`'s child blocks:

```css
.profile__dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.avatar {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.avatar--circle {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.avatar--md {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}
.user-info>* {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.user-info-text {
    padding-left: 4px;
    max-width: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.user-info-text>* {
    display: block;
}
.user-info-text>*,
.profile__info a, 
.profile__info span, 
.profile__info li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.profile__dropdown li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #777;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    float: initial;
}
.profile__info a {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: initial;
}
.profile__detail a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 30px;
}
.profile__wrapper li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.profile__dropdown li.separate {
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
}
.profile__dropdown li a, .user-info {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="profile__dropdown">
    <li class="user-info">
        <div class="avatar avatar--circle avatar--md"></div>
        <div class="user-info-text"><span>John Joe adfasdfadfadsf</span><span>0011026184</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="separate"><a href="#">Settings adfadfasdfasdfdsfadsf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, you could try to use [display: table-cell + max-width: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292408/why-does-this-behave-the-way-it-does-with-max-width-0) hack, but then you'll have to add additional wrappers to your HTML.

Check out the snippet below, I've added `.user-info__cell` elements:

```css
.profile__dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.avatar {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.avatar--circle {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.avatar--md {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}
.user-info>* {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.user-info__cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
}
.user-info__cell--text {
    max-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.user-info-text {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.user-info-text>* {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.profile__dropdown li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #777;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    float: initial;
}
.profile__info a {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: initial;
}
.profile__detail a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 30px;
}
.profile__wrapper li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.profile__dropdown li.separate {
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
}
.profile__dropdown li a, .user-info {
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="profile__dropdown">
    <li class="user-info">
        <div class="user-info__cell">
            <div class="avatar avatar--circle avatar--md"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="user-info__cell user-info__cell--text">
            <div class="user-info-text">
                <span>John Joe adfasdfadfadsf</span>
                <span>0011026184</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="separate"><a href="#">Settings adfadfasdfasdfdsfadsf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey.Yes you're right that text-overflow is apply to block element and the element it self is a block element but the parent is `inline-block` that was the problem. Is it possible without using max-width I need it to be flexible.

Comment: @YonasHailu `inline-block` is not a problem. The problem is that you need to limit `width`. Check out my answer, I've updated it.

Comment: @YonasHailu did it help you?