# How can I make horizontal scroll bar only code block in <td>?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make some custom table with HTML and SASS. I searched many questions on this site, but none of them works for my case.

the properties of the table are:

- table with 'width: 100%'
- responsive column width (according to contents)

  - first two columns are responsive with their contents and
  - third (the last) column width: 100% - width of (first + second) column

    - the third column has 'code' and this code display in a single line 
      (line-breaking in the other blocks are ok)
    - If the 'code' goes too long, a horizontal scroll bar will show up.
      (the scroll bar only affects the 'code'. No scroll bar at 'td' but 'code'.)

I've already done with:

```
table-layout: fixed
```

: It works partially. But the column widths are divided equally across the table, regardless of content inside the cells. I need a responsive column. 
(If you activate the line 10 of SASS in my demo below, you can see what I said.)

```
overflow-x: scroll, auto, ...
```

: I succeeded to make scroll bar in the code block. But the width of the table exceeds the 'width: 100%'. In other words, the width of  (which has the code block) stretches unlimitedly.
(This is demonstrated in my the demo below.)

here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/purhvf0b/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the below sass to `td`

```
 td
    border: 1px solid #444444
    width: 1px
```

also add the below sass to third column (I have added a class `longtd` to third td)

```
.longtd
  overflow: auto
  max-width: 0;
  width: auto;
```

forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Soothran/n57m0f1b/

http://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/ty4gof03/

Comment: The second one works perfect! (Actually, I edited the question, after the first answer is posted.) WOw. Thanks! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have an extra question.... what is the magic of 'td width: 1px' and 'max-width: 0'.
Both are essential but I cannot understand what these codes do...

Comment: @heeam-shin please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292408/why-does-this-behave-the-way-it-does-with-max-width-0

Comment: I still cannot fully understand... But I will try. Thanks for the very kind answer!

Answer (score 0):

try this

**css**

```
.width-100-border {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
table td{
   border: 1px solid #444444;
   max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works with fixed width but I have to display the table in many resolutions (such as tablet, phone.,,). So I need a responsive column.

Comment: The changed code makes scroll bar in column small resolution. Without it, it work good. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can use m-custom-scrollbar jquery plugin
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/