# How can I set the widths of html table columns without individual styling of cells?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find the best way to dynamically set the width of a table column, without having to set the width of each cell individually.

I have a table where each column should have a fixed width, regardless of the contents. This works fine if every cell has a width and a max-width set individually. But this is awkward to set dynamically.

I'm trying to use the colgroup and col tags to set the width of each column, but this doesn't seem to work.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 50px; max-width: 50px;">
    <col style="width: 50px; max-width: 50px;">
    <col style="width: 50px; max-width: 50px;">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5869207</td>
    <td>My first CSS</td>
    <td>$49</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expected the example to show the first and second columns of the table truncated, but it doesn't work.

Comment: to fix a width for a table, you need to reset the table-layout property to fixed  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout  Setting width on the col element is a good way to go. I'd be surprised that max-width worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wonder if this will do the trick - you can set width/max-width on the headers only, and then max-width: 0 for all cells and it seems to achieve what you want...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
  max-width: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50px; max-width:50px">ISBN</th>
    <th style="width:50px; max-width:50px">Title</th>
    <th style="width:50px; max-width:50px">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>347689643</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5869207</td>
    <td>My first CSS</td>
    <td>$49</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If anyone would like to dig into why max-width: 0 works in this case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292408/why-does-this-behave-the-way-it-does-with-max-width-0

Comment: Interesting. Is this behaviour standard among all browsers?

Comment: OK, seems to be standard. At least Vivaldi, Chrome, Firefox and Edge support this on the desktop.

Comment: @LarsMelander Yeah, the link in my comment has more info about this case and why it is cross-browser as well. max-width, width, and the table-cell display type are all well supported and it's in those implementations that this effect is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like if you add a span="3" and a width="#ofPixels" ie: width="100" to your colgroup element it will specify a width for your columns.

Comment: Also if you need it to scroll, replace overflow: hidden with overflow: scroll.

Comment: ?? have you tried max-width and overflow:scroll on a table or table element ?

Comment: How does this let the OP declare width per column? Your code just applies width to all cells - the OP is about declaring a fixed width per column.

Comment: @MrRobboto My fault man, didn't know you wanted for the columns specifically. I didn't read that correctly.

Comment: I'm not the OP lol but no problem! Just figured I'd point it out, wasn't going to down vote or anything...

Comment: @MrRobboto Yeah, it looks like colgroup has properties to edit your col widths.

Comment: @MBri yep, or just do it on the headers per my answer, a little bit simpler, less markup.

Comment: Maybe, but this is not valid HTML5.

Comment: @LarsMelander but it is though, specifically for your colgroup element https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-colgroup-width-attribute/

Comment: @MBri This page says otherwise:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup