# Setting the height of a textarea inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set the height of my textarea to 500%, but for some reason it's not changing to 500%. I think it has something to do with it being inside a table, but I'm not sure what to change set the height correctly. For some reason, the width of the textarea CAN be change inside the table.

```css
table,td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
textarea {
resize: none;
width: 100%;
height: 500%;
}
```

```html
<table> 
<tr>

<td> 
firstTD 
</td> 

<td>
<form method = 'POST' action = 'updateProfile.php'>
<textarea id = 'textarea' placeholder = 'type something here...' onfocus = \"this.placeholder = ''\" onblur = \"this.placeholder = 'type something here...'\" maxlength = '10000'></textarea>
</form>
</td>

</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943721/3063226, using box-sizing: border-box; for the textarea is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer solves the problem, but doesn't explain it. When you use % to define width/height in CSS, you are making it whatever% of that element's container' width/height.

When you set your textarea to be 100% of an otherwise empty `<td>`, it's not going to be very big.

Setting it to posistion:absolute will work IF none the ancestor elements are positioned. A simpler approach would be to just use something other than % to define your width and height. Try `width:10em;` and adjust it until you get it right.

**Edit.**

To answer a question in the comments: The reason using % to define the height works in this case, is because the empty cell has a height, but not a width. An empty table cell still inherits the height of the row, which is as tall as the tallest `<td>`. In this case there is another `<td>` that has content, giving the cell a height.

So, If there was another row, and one of the cells in the same column had content, then width would work with % too.

That said, it's not a good idea to use % for width and height in a table, because when the content in the table changes, your percentages will change. Also, when you use % as opposed to px or em, it will not stretch the parent container.

**Edit again**

I honestly didn't even notice the form element. Then your percents are relative to the height/width of the form element, not the `<td>`. There must be some padding giving your cells width/height but the form wouldn't have any dimensions.

Comment: I explained it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301906/setting-the-height-of-a-textarea-inside-a-table/34301935?noredirect=1#comment56346033_34301935

Comment: It is as you said. Changing it to em or px solves the problem immediately. Also, you explained it in a way that made me understand what I did wrong, and what to look out for in the future.

Comment: That's a good thing to know. However if that's the case then even the % on width shouldn't work. right ? Just curious.

Comment: @DinoMyte That's what he's saying. % doesn't work, so switch over to either em or px.

Comment: @DinoMyte, yes it is. you are using % there. use em like i said: https://jsfiddle.net/t5thymzq/2/ do you understand now?

Comment: @Pamblam, I understand that using em or px over % works for height, but it don't justify why % works on width and not height.

Comment: @DinoMyte Maybe. Because % works for both height and width if you take off the form element.

Comment: Ooooh, i honestly didn't even notice the form element. Then your percents are relative to the height/width of the form element, not the `<td>`..  that's why. there must be some padding giving your cells width/height but the form wouldn't have any dimensions.

Comment: Apparently, seems like it has something to do specific to html tables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846045/understanding-css-table-cell-and-percentage-width

Comment: nope. you're making it complicated again. read the w3schools page for css width and height and look at the table that explains what % does.

Comment: tables are just wierd because their width and height are determined by several factors..

Comment: Man, I'm starting to hate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `position: absolute` to `textarea` and give a `position: relative` to the parent. Also remove `width` and give `left` and `right` values as `0`. But remember, this will make the `textarea` to overflow out of the content. Is that what you are expecting?

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 500%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      firstTD
    </td>
    <td>
      <form method='POST' action='updateProfile.php'>
        <textarea id='textarea' placeholder='type something here...' onfocus=\ "this.placeholder = ''\" onblur=\ "this.placeholder = 'type something here...'\" maxlength='10000'></textarea>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or if you need something like this?

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      firstTD
    </td>
    <td>
      <form method='POST' action='updateProfile.php'>
        <textarea id='textarea' placeholder='type something here...' onfocus=\ "this.placeholder = ''\" onblur=\ "this.placeholder = 'type something here...'\" maxlength='10000'></textarea>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The textarea's all messed up.

Comment: @frosty Updated. Sorry buddy.

Comment: Is there a way to keep it inside the td?

Comment: @frosty `500% > 100%` Do you understand?

Comment: @frosty Kindly check the updated answer and accept it if it is what you are expecting.

Comment: i feel like you guys are making this more difficult than it needs to be. just use explicit units when defining the width and height and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can set size for text area

```
$("textarea").css("height", $("textarea").parent("td").height())
.css("width", $("textarea").parent("td").width())
```